# How to place text into div created in external javascript file .js

Tags: javascript

I have question. How to put div into external javascipt file (.js)? What is syntax? Not .js into div that is already in html page but in .js file! This question here is reapeted and modified.

I repeat the code below is in .js file!

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = "100px";
div.style.height = "100px";
div.style.background = "red";
div.style.color = "white";
```

What I want to do is to place code below into div writen in javascript eternal file .js! In the same .js file as code above.

```
  document.write("<h1>This is a heading</h1>");
  document.write("<p>This is a paragraph</p>");
```

Comment: No, I need text to be inserted into div in the same .js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div.innerHTML = '<h1>This is a heading</h1><p>This is a paragraph</p>';
```

For a large number of strings, you can concatenate them:

```
var str = '<h1>This is a heading</h1';
str += '<p>This is a paragraph</p>';
str += '<p>This is a another paragraph</p>';
...
div.innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: Is there a way to put large number of document.write into div created above something like in html <div id="idname">some text</div> ?

Comment: `document.write` is an outdated way to update the DOM. You should use DOM manipulation methods.